# How can I take mongo documents with different structure in the same collection and match them based on a common field and return a custom document

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in the same collection with different fields one they might look like

```
{
  _id: 1
  commonCodeId: 1234,
  description: this is description
  favoriteIceCream: green
  
},
{
  _id: 2
  commonCodeId: 1234,
  fieldINeedToAddInCustomDocument: this needs to be added to document with _id:1
  
},
{
  _id: 3
  commonCodeId: 1234,
  anotherFieldINeedToAddInCustomDocument: this needs to be added to document with _id:1
  
}
```

I need to go through these and return a document that looks like

```
{
  _id: newDocumentCreated,
  commonCodeId: 1234,
  description: this is description
  favoriteIceCream: green
  fieldINeedToAddInCustomDocument: this needs to be added to document with _id:1
  anotherFieldINeedToAddInCustomDocument: this needs to be added to document with _id:1
}
```

So I need to aggregate then match on commonCodeId and create a new document with everything from object with _id: 1 plus select fields from _id: 2 and _id: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this aggregation

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "commonCodeId": 1234
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$commonCodeId",
      "orig": {
        $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$orig"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWG-d1UZ7Iq

Comment: You could change place of ‘match’